# Case Hierarchy in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Hi I have to create a custom component in which i have to display the hierarchy of case.

Issue is only the first level hierarchy is display not the other level.

Apex

```
public with sharing class DynamicTreeGridController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Case> getAllParentAccounts(Id recordId) {
        return [SELECT CaseNumber, Type FROM Case WHERE Id =: recordId];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> getChildAccounts(Id parentId) {
        return [
            SELECT CaseNumber, Type
            FROM Case
            WHERE ParentId = :parentId
        ];
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-tree-grid
            columns={gridColumns}
            data={gridData}
            is-loading={isLoading}
            key-field="Id"
            ontoggle={handleOnToggle}
        ></lightning-tree-grid>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire ,api} from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

// Import the schema
import CASENUMBER from "@salesforce/schema/Case.CaseNumber";

// Import Apex
import getAllParentAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/DynamicTreeGridController.getAllParentAccounts";
import getChildAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/DynamicTreeGridController.getChildAccounts";

// Global Constants
const COLS = [
    { fieldName: "CaseNumber", label: "Case Number" }
    // { fieldName: "CaseURL", label: "Case Number" , type: "url",
    // typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: "CaseNumber" }, tooltip: "Name", target: "_blank"}}
    // { fieldName: "ParentAccountName", label: "Parent Account" },
    // { fieldName: "Type", label: "Account Type" }
];

export default class DynamicTreeGrid extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    gridColumns = COLS;
    isLoading = true;
    gridData = [];
    finalData = [];

    @wire(getAllParentAccounts, {recordId: '$recordId'})
    parentAccounts({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
            console.error("error loading accounts", error);
        } else if (data) {
            this.gridData = data.map((account) => ({
                _children: [],
                ...account
                //CaseURL: this.gridData.forEach(item => item['CaseURL'] = '/lightning/r/Case/' + item['Id'] + '/view')
                //ParentAccountName: account.Parent?.Name
            }));
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
    }

    handleOnToggle(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.name);
        console.log(event.detail.hasChildrenContent);
        console.log(event.detail.isExpanded);
        console.log('recordId=='+this.recordId);
        const rowName = event.detail.name;
        if (!event.detail.hasChildrenContent && event.detail.isExpanded) {
            this.isLoading = true;
            getChildAccounts({ parentId: this.recordId })
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    if (result && result.length > 0) {
                        const newChildren = result.map((child) => ({
                            _children: [],
                            ...child
                           // CaseURL: this.gridData.forEach(item => item['CaseURL'] = '/lightning/r/Case/' + item['Id'] + '/view')
                            //ParentAccountName: child.Parent?.Name
                        }));
                        this.gridData = this.getNewDataWithChildren(
                            this.recordId,
                            this.gridData,
                            newChildren
                        );
                    } else {
                        this.dispatchEvent(
                            new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: "No children",
                                message: "No children for the selected Account",
                                variant: "warning"
                            })
                        );
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error loading child accounts", error);
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: "Error Loading Children Accounts",
                            message: error + " " + error?.message,
                            variant: "error"
                        })
                    );
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                });
        }
    }

    getNewDataWithChildren(rowName, data, children) {
        return data.map((row) => {
            let hasChildrenContent = false;
            if (
                Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(row, "_children") &&
                Array.isArray(row._children) &&
                row._children.length > 0
            ) {
                hasChildrenContent = true;
            }

            if (row.Id === rowName) {
                row._children = children;
            } else if (hasChildrenContent) {
                this.getNewDataWithChildren(this.recordId, row._children, children);
            }
            return row;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason to build this from scratch. This is a [standard feature](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cases_parent.htm&type=5) available in Lightning Experience.

Comment: Also there is a custom solution [Any Record Hierarchy](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MBe9WEAT&_ga=2.33183806.1899071790.1676266858-1890760398.1675247782&legacy=true) available from Salesforce Labs which can be used in LWC applications.